# Problem with ALB Ingress Controller in redirecting to right path

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I have done the setup of ALB (Application Load Balancer) using Ingress Controller (**version -> docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.8**) for my AWS EKS cluster (**v 1.20**) running with Fargate profile.

I can access my service using the load balancer link:-

http://5e07dbe1-default-nginxingr-29e9-1260427999.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/

[image]

I have 2 different services configured in my Ingress as shown below:-

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "nginx-ingress"
  namespace: "default"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-014b302d73097d083
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:195725532069:certificate/b6a9e691-b807-4f10-a0bf-0449730ecdf4
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    #alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: "60"
    #alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      # - path: /*
      #   pathType: Prefix
      #   backend:
      #     service:
      #        name: ssl-redirect
      #        port: 
      #          number: use-annotation
      - path: /foo
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: "nginx-service"
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
             name: "mydocker-svc"
             port: 
               number: 8080
```

Now the problem is if I put **/foo** at the end of LB link then nothing happens and I get 404 not found error:-

[image]

Both my services are fine with respective Pods running behind their respective Kubernetes NodePort services but they are not accessible using the Ingress. If I swap the path to **/*** from **/foo** for the other service (**nginx-service**), I can then access that but then it will break my previous service (**mydocker-svc**).

Please let me know where I'm the mistake so that I can fix this issue. Thank you

ALB Controller:-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: alb-ingress-controller
        args:
        - --ingress-class=alb
        - --cluster-name=eks-fargate-alb-demo
        - --aws-vpc-id=vpc-0dc46d370e38de475
        - --aws-region=us-east-1
        image: docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.8
      serviceAccountName: alb-ingress-controller
```

Nginx service:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
  name: "nginx-service"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: "nginx"
```

mydocker-svc:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    eks.amazonaws.com/fargate-profile: fp-default
    run: mydocker
  name: mydocker-svc
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    eks.amazonaws.com/fargate-profile: fp-default
    run: mydocker
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

TargetGroups become unhealthy, if the annotation in Kubernetes NodePort service like alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: IP is missing:-
[image]

Comment: What does your NGINX configuration look like?

Comment: @EgeKaanGürkan, I have added the configuration files in the same question...pls advise....I have tried a lot debugging it but not sure where the mistake is, thanks

Comment: Is your nginx able to serve `<endpoint>/foo` ? Or are you expecting the `/foo` path on the LB to be re-written to `/` for the nginx? Because [that feature](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/835) is not yet available for ALB.

Comment: @mreferre I know path rewrite is not yet available but I'm expecting my respective service calls when I do <dns endpoint>/foo or <dns endpoint>/bar because this is what an ingress is supposed to perform :)

Comment: Fair enough. I was just ruling that out. If your code responds at /bar and /foo then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @vinod827 why is the `target_type` set to `ip`? I am not sure but it might be related to that. Also, did you try adding `/*` to the end of the path? Like so: `/foo/*`

Comment: @EgeKaanGürkan , pls attached screenshot that I just uploaded above in the question. The problem is if I do not put this annotation alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: IP ...TargetGroup will not have any healthy endpoints, so load balancer does not know where to redirect the traffic. That means problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this out one i am using as reference

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-usermgmt-restapp-service
  labels:
    app: usermgmt-restapp
  annotations:
    # Ingress Core Settings
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    # Health Check Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
#Important Note:  Need to add health check path annotations in service level if we are planning to use multiple targets in a load balancer    
    #alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /usermgmt/health-status
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app1/*
            backend:
              serviceName: app1-nginx-nodeport-service
              servicePort: 80                        
          - path: /app2/*
            backend:
              serviceName: app2-nginx-nodeport-service
              servicePort: 80            
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: usermgmt-restapp-nodeport-service
              servicePort: 8095
```

Read more at : https://www.stacksimplify.com/aws-eks/aws-alb-ingress/kubernetes-aws-alb-ingress-context-path-based-routing/